# XSL copies attributes of ancestor nodes while I need attributes from context node only

Tags: xslt

I am copying the descendant tree of Body. In the output, how can I suppress all attributes except xmlns="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201605" which is int the child node.

Here is the input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:RequestHeader
         soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
         soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"
         xmlns:ns1="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201605">
      <ns1:networkCode>123456</ns1:networkCode>
      <ns1:applicationName>DfpApi-Java-2.1.0-dfp_test</ns1:applicationName>
    </ns1:RequestHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getAdUnitsByStatement xmlns="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201605">
      <filterStatement>
        <query>WHERE parentId IS NULL LIMIT 500</query>
      </filterStatement>
    </getAdUnitsByStatement>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".//*:Body/* " />  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output:

```
<getAdUnitsByStatement xmlns="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201605"
              xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <filterStatement>
    <query>WHERE parentId IS NULL LIMIT 500</query>
    </filterStatement>
  </getAdUnitsByStatement>
```

Thanks.

Sandeep

Comment: It helps to know that as far as XSLT is concerned, these are not attribute nodes, but namespace nodes: hopefully that will help you find the right information in your favourite reference book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really use an XSLT 3.0 processor or at least an XSLT 2.0 processor then replace

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select=".//*:Body/* " />  
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//*:Body/* " copy-namespaces="no"/>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perfect. This works. You made my day. Thanks Martin.